# How do I convert a duration string to number?

Tags: google-sheets

In a Google sheet, I have a list of rows with a length attached to each:

> Example 1 - 1h 30m

Using a formula, I need to convert "1h 30m" to a numerical value.
The longest duration I have in the sheet are 4 digit durations (ie 1000h 30m)

Does anyone know how to best do this?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/143497) help you ?

Comment: I don't think so because the person in that particular thread set up his numbers using duration formatting, whereas I did not. My durations are simply text strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the text string `1h 30m` is in cell `B2`, use a `regexreplace()` formula in another cell, like this:

`=to_date( value( regexreplace(B2, "(\d+)h (\d+)m", "$1:$2") ) )`

Format the formula cell as **Format > Number > Duration** or a custom time format of your choosing.

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

To learn the exact [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: I'm getting a Formula Parse Error for that formula. 
Am I supposed to substitute anything in that formula (ie "value")?

I did edit B2 to reflect the correct text string but the Formula Parse Error remained.

Comment: In the event your spreadsheet locale uses commas `,` as decimal separators, you will have to use semicolons `;` as formula argument separators. Replace the two commas in the formula with semicolons.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

quick follow up question - what if I wanted to do a reverse conversion? 
so e.g. 9:00 -> 9h 00m - how would that work?

If you think that warrants a separate post, let me know and I'll make one :)

Comment: It usually makes more sense to use a _custom number format_ to present durations in the format you need. You can then get the data as text strings with `to_text()` if necessary. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).